# Custom Label in Django Formset

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms, formset

How do I add custom labels to my formset?

```
<form method="post" action="">

    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

My model is:

```
class Sing(models.Model):
song = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
band = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

Now in the template instead of the field label being `'song'`, how do i set it so that it shows up as `'What song are you going to sing?'`?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom labels"? How should they look? Where should they be displayed? What's the point of that template extract?

Comment: sorrt for being unclear. view edits?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `label` argument in your form:

```
class MySingForm(forms.Form):
    song = forms.CharField(label='What song are you going to sing?')
    ...
```

If you are using `ModelForms`:

```
class MySingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['song'].label = 'What song are you going to sing?'
  
    class Meta:
        model = Sing
```

### Update:

#### (*@Daniel Roseman's comment*)

Or in the model (using `verbose_name`):

```
class Sing(models.Model):
    song = models.CharField(verbose_name='What song are you going to sing?',
                            max_length=50)
    ...
```

or

```
class Sing(models.Model):
    song = models.CharField('What song are you going to sing?', max_length=50)
    ...
```

Comment: i get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label'`

Comment: `label` should be `verbose_name`, or just use the first positional argument.

Comment: Answer updated. `label` argument is used only with `Form` fields not `Model` fields (my mistake). Can you post your form definition so that I can give you a 100% working solution?

Comment: I was using ModelForm `class SingForm(ModelForm): Class Meta: model = Sing`

Comment: The solution with `verbose_name` in model field should do the trick.