# Change login label in Django auth form

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to change the login username label but without any success. Here is the website:

[image]

What I'd like to do is print "Usuário and e-mail" instead of just "Usuário" label:

I didn't customize the login form, in this way, I'm using all standard auth process.

```
   #template
   <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
        <p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
    </form>
```

If you guys have any suggestion modifying the input field through CSS style, it's welcome as well!

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
       {% for field in form %}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {% if field.label_tag == 'Usuário' %}
                    {% field.label_tag = 'Usuário ou e-mail:' %}
                {% elif %}
                    {{ field.label_tag }}
                {% endif %}
             {{ field.label_tag }}{{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5949872/6648059), it's clear and straight forward.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/5949872/6648059](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5949872/6648059)

Comment: Thomas, thx but the problem is: this is a Django standard form. In this way, I didn't create it. How am I suppose to create a new User form?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369645/how-to-customize-default-auth-login-form-in-django

Comment: Thomas, nice: this question is helping me but I got stuck in the EDIT code in the main question. Could you help me, pls?

Comment: This question has already been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636905/django-form-set-label.

Answer (score 0):

Value the **label** in the attribute **form**.

Comment: I didn't create a class form for this fields. They came automatically from the Django standard...